# Websockets not working on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket, socket.io

I recently deployed a node.js server application to Google App Engine that communicates with a client application via socket.io. Accordingly to [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity), websockets are now supported on App Engine.

However, the client app is unable to connect to the server over the wss protocol. I can see the following error message in the browser console. (I removed my server domain)

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://[my server]/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=dbB2UgsCYhD7c1ucAAAA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Socket.io then falls back to https long polling, which works well.

Here is my app.yaml for deployment to app engine, with session_affinity set to true for long polling.

```
runtime: nodejs10

instance_class: F2

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto

network:
  session_affinity: true
```

Socket.io is used on the server in a straightforward way:

```
this.server = this.app.listen(this.PORT, (err: any) => {
  io = socketio().listen(this.server);
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log('A socket connection was made!');
  });
});
```

I am wondering how to get the websocket connection to work on App Engine? Maybe a firewall rule or other configuration change is needed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

const forceSecure = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.secure)
     return next(); // https -- Continue

  res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url)
}

/**
* This will force
* ALL HTTP requests ( GET, POST, OPTIONS, etc. )
* on ALL route handlers to be
* redirected to https 
*/
app.all('*', forceSecure);

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('example');
  res.end();
});

app.ws('/', (ws, req) => {
  ws.on('message', msg => {
    console.log(msg);
  });
  console.log('socket', req.example);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

---

As of now, WebSockets are [only supported in the Flexible Environment for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-websockets-support-for-app-engine-flexible-environment). From what I see, you are deploying your application in the Standard Environment, as denoted by the [instance_class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) you specified: `instance_class: F2`. Thus, I would suggest changing the environment from Standard to Flexible, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) for the app.yaml Configuration File in Flex. Doing so, will allow you to take advantage of the WebSockets functionality recently implemented in App Engine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know, can I still use the handlers section in the app.yaml if I switch to the flexible environment? The flex docs do not list that section: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, `handlers` can only be used in App Engine Standard. You can create route handlers by code however. Personally, I have used [express-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws) in the past which, if you had any experience writing `express.js` applications, lets you write WebSockets endpoints similar to how you would write any other route handler.

Comment: Thanks again. I guess my only concern with the handlers would be how to redirect traffic from http to https in the flex env.

Comment: No worries, you can also force https to be used through code. Assuming [express-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws) was used, you can create a middleware which will redirect all unsecured traffic to https and attach it to all route handlers for all http methods. I edited my answer accordingly to give you an illustration on how this could work.